# Multiple video track layers in iMovie?

Tags: imovie

I have a four videos of the same event (a band playing) all taken from different angles.

I'd like to make a concert video of the footage.  Nothing special, just cut from angle to angle throughout the song -- use the guitar player close up on the guitar solo -- that sort of thing.

Is there a way in iMovie to layout each video in a separate "layer" (sort of like in Photoshop), and then (after I sync them to the audio), movie the "camera" from one layer to another?

If iMovie can't do that, is there other software that can?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't really do this in iMovie as it is limited to 2 video tracks. You can do it in Final Cut or Premiere Pro if you're willing to spend the money, or HitFilm Express if you want don't want to spend a penny.

Comment: isn't that amazing that we live in 21st century and it's the case.. 
btw ffmpeg is perfectly capable of generating anything and it cost nothing. I'm solving the similar challenge this days as an author of the question > multiple video streams and I'm a musician who can code.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I found a solution, a bit like the old days when recording a tape:

- create your 2 camera angle video then bounce them into a new timeline in a new project and finaly add the third camera to the extra timeline in that new project,

or

- alternatively create 2 separate files, both with 2 camera angle videos, and bounce them into a third new file in order to have 2 timelines with 2 cameras on each and edit them to one final video with 4 camera angles,

Hope that makes sense!